# Why does the program not calculate the value correctly?

Tags: c++

I have a task. I need to evaluate the expression:

w = (3x + 6x + 9x ... + 90x) -15   , x = 0.03

The calculation of this expression should occur using a while loop.

I wrote the program code, but I get the impression that it does not work correctly.

Please see if my code is working correctly? I am very inexperienced = (

```
double x = 0.03;
double w, sum;
int counter1 = 0;
while (counter1 <= 90) {
    counter1 += 3;
    w = counter1 * x;
    sum = sum + w;
}
sum = sum - 15;
cout << "Calculation result, w =: " << sum << endl;
```

Comment: Did you try using a debugger to run your program one line at a time, letting you inspect the values of all variables as they change, while you observe your program's execution? Do you know how to use a debugger? If not, now is a good opportunity to do so. Knowing how to use a debugger is a mandatory skill for every C++ developer. No, your code is obviously not working correctly because of a simple bug, and you should be able to figure out your bug immediately, when you run your program in your debugger.

Comment: Shouldn't the while condition be `counter1 < 90` since using `counter1 <= 90` would add an additional `(90 + 3)x = 93x` into the `3x + 6x + 9x ... + 90x` part?

Comment: Thank you very much, now everything works correctly =)

Comment: Do yourself a favor and simplify.  You can factor out 3 from each term:  `3 * (x + 2x + 3x ...)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your problem is the first time through the loop:

```
sum = sum + w;
```

`sum` is uninitialised so it can contain any garbage.

You should always initialise variables:

```
double sum = 0;
```

Also, as @formerlyknownas_463035818 comments, your loop goes too far:

```
while (counter1 <= 90) {
    counter1 += 3;
    ...
```

your last term will be `93 * x`, not `90 * x` as you intended.

So it should be:

```
while (counter1 < 90) {
    counter1 += 3;
    ...
```

Comment: and the last term will be `93*x` not `90*x`